# Why nginx virtual host is not available from internet?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I made a `virtual host` with nginx and I've add to `host`:

```
127.0.0.1        testapp
```

the virtual host   `http://testapp` is available on my `VPS` but via from internet is not accessible:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  testapp testapp.51.x.x.172;
        ##root   html;
        root c:/apps/web;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried proxy reverse?

Comment: Why would be accessible from internet? You need a domain and DNS resolution settings done, for your server to be reachable from internet

Comment: Dear @tarun-lalwani I have static IP address and Domian. but still is not working.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: I use this url: `testapp.51.x.x.172` but page is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `DNS` problem.
You had to define a `CNAME record` on your host like `testapp` FQDN will be `testapp.yourdomain.com` and target host should be your `yourdomain.com` which is already registered `A record`.

In your host you should add this line.

```
127.0.0.1    testapp.yourdomain.com
```

your problem was finished 
But you probably need to done a `proxy revers` on your web server.